# Append Function Nested Inside IF Statement Body Not Working

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append

I am fairly new to Python (just started learning in the last two weeks) and am trying to write a script to parse a csv file to extract some of the fields into a List:

```
from string import Template
import csv
import string

site1 = 'D1'
site2 = 'D2'
site3 = 'D5'
site4 = 'K0'
site5 = 'K1'
site6 = 'K2'
site7 = '0'
site8 = '0'
site9 = '0'
lbl = 1
portField = 'y'
sw = 5
swpt = 6
cd = 0
pt = 0
natList = []
with open(name=r'C:\Users\dtruman\Documents\PROJECTS\SCRIPTING - NATAERO DEPLOYER\NATAERO DEPLOYER V1\nataero_deploy.csv') as rcvr:
    for line in rcvr:
        fields = line.split(',')
        Site = fields[0]
        siteList = [site1,site2,site3,site4,site5,site6,site7,site8,site9]
        while Site in siteList == True:
            Label = fields[lbl]
            Switch = fields[sw]
            if portField == 'y':
                Switchport = fields[swpt]
                natList.append([Switch,Switchport,Label])
            else:
                Card = fields[cd]
                Port = fields[pt]
                natList.append([Switch,Card,Port,Label])
print natList
```

Even if I strip the ELSE statement away and break into my code right after the IF clause-- i can verify that "Switchport" (first statement in IF clause) is successfully being populated with a Str from my csv file, as well as "Switch" and "Label".  However, "natList" is not being appended with the fields parsed from each line of my csv for some reason.  Python returns no errors-- just does not append "natList" at all.

This is actually going to be a function (once I get the code itself to work), but for now, I am simply setting the function parameters as global variables for the sake of being able to run it in an iPython console without having to call the function.

The "lbl", "sw", "swpt", "cd", and "pt" refer to column#'s in my csv (the finished function will allow user to enter values for these variables).

I assume I am running into some issue with "natList" scope-- but I have tried moving the "natList = []" statement to various places in my code to no avail.

I can run the above in a console, and then run "append.natList([Switch,Switchport,Label])" separately and it works for some reason....?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: just a suggestion.. you should probably add a python tag to your post so that people are more likely to see it. I usually just browse posts that contain particular tags. Sadly i know next to nothing about python - yet. Hope you find an answer.

Comment: Thanks!  New to this site....

Comment: no problem  me too - There will be plenty of people telling you how to post if they don't think you've done it properly :) Think of it as help. Sometimes they can be pretty blunt as well. Don't read too much into it. Try here btw .. http://stackoverflow.com/help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that the while condition needs an additional parenthesis. Just add some in this way `while (Site in siteList) == True:` or a much cleaner way suggested by Padraic `while Site in siteList:`.

It was comparing boolean object against string object.

Comment: BTW, I would change that while for an if-clause. Because it will execute that loop indefinitely

Comment: Good catch.  Now when I run it-- it locks up my computer for a moment and then gives me a memory error.

Comment: I got it!  Thanks for the assist inulinmux12.  I had to add parentheses around "Site in sitelist" statement like you said and changed the "while" loop into an "if" statement and now its working.

Comment: `while Site in siteList:` would be the correct way.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while Site in siteList == True:
```

to

```
if Site in siteList:
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the `csv` module as this module attempts to make reading and writing csv files simpler, e.g.:

```
import csv

with open('<file>') as fp:
    ...
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    if portfield == 'y':
        natlist = [[row[i] for i in [sw, swpt, lbl]] for row in fp if row[0] in sitelist]
    else:
        natlist = [[row[i] for i in [sw, cd, pt, lbl]] for row in fp if row[0] in sitelist]

print natlist
```

Or alternatively using a `csv.DictReader` which takes the first row as the fieldnames and then returns dictionaries:

```
import csv

with open('<file>') as fp:
    ...
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    if portfield == 'y':
        fields = ['Switch', 'card/port', 'Label']
    else:
        fields = ['Switch', '??', '??', 'Label']
    natlist = [[row[f] for f in fields] for row in fp if row['Building/Site'] in sitelist]

print natlist
```